# Remove the space padding margin around a ListViewItem

Tags: wpf, xaml

Would like to add style to the button, and don't understand why I have to include this line of code, where I don't want to add any Border to my button:

```
<Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
```

The complete code:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleRed" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200">
                        <Rectangle Width="4" Height="30" Fill="#64dd17" Margin="0,0,10,1" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.FlowStageName,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                 </Border>
                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#263238"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#37474f"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
</Style>
```

I would keep this like that but there are some other padding or margin issues which I can't resolved too.

When I don't have this border, Setter Property for Background color also doesn't work.

**EDIT**
When I change it to below, it leave me with the padding/margin around the button. 
I have set Setters for Margin and Padding to 0, but this doesn't work.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="200" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                      <Rectangle Width="4" Height="30" Fill="#64dd17" Margin="0,0,10,1" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
                      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.FlowStageName,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" 
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                 </StackPanel>
```

[image]

**EDIT2**

```
<views:BaseView.Resources>
    <views:SwapBooleanValueConverter x:Key="SwapBooleanValueConverter" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="FlowStagesTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button x:Name="MenuStageButton"
                    Tag="{Binding ID}"
                    Command="{Binding DataContext.OnButtonClickCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TurulStageButton}"
                    Style="{Binding FlowStageDisplayStyle}">
            </Button>
            <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="200" Margin="0" Height="1">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0" >
                        <GradientStop Color="#263238" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#78909c" Offset="0.5" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#263238" Offset="1.0" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</views:BaseView.Resources>
<StackPanel Background="#263238">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FlowStagesSubMenu}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlowStagesTemplate}" 
              BorderThickness="0" Background="#263238" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: That Border doesn't have actual 'border', it's used just to show background here. Without it there's no element that takes that task, hence no background.

Comment: But my button looks like there is padding inside it, as background doesn't cover whole button?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So by having that `TemplateBinding` you're providing THE object inside the template to receive that property of `Background`. Without it, there's nothing for your `Setter` to actually set. Which is why Background doesn't work, because there's nothing in there accepting that property.

However you don't necessarily need the `Border` to accomplish it. You could also just take that `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` and apply it directly to your `StackPanel` since it also has a `Background` property available anyway.

Your padding and margin issues are the same thing. You have no where in there to actually accept the Setters you're specifying. So you want padding and margin you'll either need to leave your Border and add TemplateBindings for those properties, or `StackPanel` atleast supports `Margin` so you could cross the two and create "Padding" by doing;

`<StackPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"..../>`

Except then your background color will have space around it since Background is on the object that now also has margin. Make sense? Compare to a default Button template and notice what's missing. Basically the rule of thumb here is. If you want to set it at the actual control level like `<Button Background="blah" Margin="Blah"..../>` then something inside the template needs to be available for that declaration you're trying to use. At least while you're still learning how templating works anyway. Hope this helps.

**Addendum;**

Ok so since we figured out `Button` isn't actually your issue but the parent. Try this instead.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FlowStagesSubMenu}" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlowStagesTemplate}" 
          BorderThickness="0" Background="#263238"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
   <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
         <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
      </Style>
   </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I understand why, but still cant remove this border around the button. Will add changes to the question in a minute

Comment: Ah ok maybe I misunderstood what the issue was, maybe just an image or something to visualize the issue?

Comment: Are you talking about the space between the buttons? Or the Setter height you have set at 50 while your content is 30 causing the space inside the buttons?

Comment: The space is around the button, not only between buttons. Forgot to say but the buttons are on the ListView

Comment: Ah ok, goose chase haha.... So yea, the ListViewItem is your culprit. The [default template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms788717%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) has a hard set 2px padding. So when stacked 2+2=4px, kill that and you should be good.

Comment: I think I will need your help with that, don't know where to put it. Will add it to the question

Comment: That is my problem, I have added DataTemplate, but don't know where to select StyleTemplate in my example.

Comment: I have added BorderThickness to your answer and Is working perfectly good. Thank you

Comment: Good deal, glad you got your remedy!

Comment: the `BorderThickness` did the job :)